# How to share and give full access to folder and inner folder in Server 2008

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-server-2008, cmd

I have Windows Server 2008. I want to create a folder and share it in network with full access (read and write) to all, whoever access this folder and inner folders too via network from any operating system PC (Win 7 and Win XP).

I want to build up a single setup that can work on Win XP, Vista, Win 7(32 & 64), Server 2003 and Server 2008.

I have downloaded `subinacl` and run the following batch file

```
net share %1=%2 /UNLIMITED    
subinacl /share %1 /grant="S-1-1-0"=F    
subinacl /file %2 /grant="S-1-1-0"=F
```

Where `%1` and `%2` are the share name and the path of the folder respectively.

I think this command does not give everyone right to the inner folder. I want to give full share and full access to everyone for all folder and files inside the `%2` folder.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

1. Enable guest account:

   `net user guest /active:yes`
2. Share the folder:

   `net share cshare=c:\shared /GRANT:Everyone,FULL`
3. Sometimes sharing the folder doesn't give the Everyone FULL permissions, so run the Icacls command as well:

   `Icacls C:\shared /grant Everyone:F /inheritance:e /T`

Comment: I am getting error on third command though I am logged in as Administrator. Access is denied. Any help?

Comment: @JawadAmjad, maybe some of the files are owned by System? (this is just a guess though). Are you sure you are running with elevated rights?

Comment: Yes I have achieved. Sharing services were not running, Guest didnt have rights. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

The xcacls.vbs script can handle the NTFS permissions, you can download it here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825751 - you'll need to modify it slightly to get it to work on Windows 7 \ Server 2008, but if you run cscript.exe xcacls.vbs /? on a Windows 7 or Server 2008 machine it will tell you how to modify it.

Example:

grant everyone full control to C:\shared and all subfolders:

cscript.exe xcacls.vbs c:\shared /G:Everyone:F /SPEC B

You should be able to use NET SHARE to create the share as well, but it sounds like you've already got that covered:

net share cshare=c:\shared /GRANT:Everyone,FULL